# How the solar system just stay around the Sun and sSun itself?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, solar-system, stability

I know that each and every planet stay with the solar system because of sun's gravitational field. What object has the gravity to hold our solar system while the boundless universe is all around the solar system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sun and all the planets orbit the centre of the Milky Way galaxy as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thats ok. if we consider the center of the galaxy as sun. solar systems as a planet. then what is actually the center of galaxy. is it just free space or nothing

Comment: It is thought that perhaps there is a super massive black hole at the centre of the Milky Way. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center There is also dark matter in the galaxy http://earthsky.org/space/dark-matter-in-the-inner-milky-way

Comment: blackhole contains massive gravitational force.there fore it holds everything around the milkyway. but that theory is made considering the newtonian physics. what about the einsteins way. space time curvature.?